# How to change color of text field from ancestor widget?

Tags: flutter

Imagine I have a widget like this:

```
MyWidget(
  fgColor: Colors.red,
  child: Text('Hello', style: MyStyles.someStaticStyle);
)
```

Is there any way that `MyWidget` can assign the `fgColor` to the `child` text?

```
Widget build(context){
  return child; // How to apply fgColor to this?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `child` could be any `Widget`, so it's practically not possible. But if you still want to go with some workaround, here is what you're looking for:

```dart
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final Color? fgColor;
  final Widget child;

  const MyWidget({
    Key? key,
    this.fgColor,
    required this.child,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final Widget widget = child;
    if (widget is Text) {
      return Text(
        widget.data!,
        style: widget.style != null ? widget.style!.copyWith(color: fgColor) : TextStyle(color: fgColor),
      );
    }

    return Container(color: fgColor, child: child);
  }
}
```

**Usage:**

```dart
Column(
  children: [
    MyWidget(
      fgColor: Colors.red,
      child: Text('Hello'), // Red color 'Hello'
    ),
    MyWidget(
      fgColor: Colors.red,
      child: SizedBox.square(dimension: 40), // Red color box
    ),
  ],
)
```

[image]

Comment: Ya I thought about that. But looking for something more like `Theme(child: child)` and somehow passing it down to the `Text` class. I just don't know if there's anything that Text tried to bind to, or how it handles resolves the default color when none is assigned.

Comment: Seems like I should able to do this with `DefaultTextStyle` somehow...

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I can use `ColorFiltered` for this:

```
return ColorFiltered(
  colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(fgColor, BlendMode.srcIn),
  child: children);
```

[image]

Seems like I should be able to do this by providing a `DefaultTextStyle` above the child, but I couldn't seem to make it work.